# Polymorphism when one argument is not always used

Tags: scala, oop, inheritance, functional-programming, polymorphism

In order to explain the problem I've simplified my code.

Regarding the following classes and object:

```
abstract class AbstractFoo { 
  def func: (A, B) => Unit = Bar1.func
}

class ConcreteFoo extends AbstractFoo {
  override def func: (A, B) => Unit = Bar2.func
}

object Bar1{
  def func(a: A, b: B): Unit = {
    println(a.toString)
    println(b.toString)
  }
}

object Bar2{
  def func(a: A, b: B): Unit = {
    println(b.toString)
  }
}
```

What I don't like is that Bar2.func accepts an A although it doesn't use it. I want to change the code so Bar2 will look like this:

```
object Bar2{
  def func(b: B): Unit = {
    println(b.toString)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No problem. Change `Bar` to

```
object Bar2{
  def func(b: B): Unit = {
    println(b.toString)
  }
}
```

as you wanted and update `ConcreteFoo` correspondingly

```
class ConcreteFoo extends AbstractFoo {
  override def func: (A, B) => Unit = (_, b) => Bar2.func(b)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change of signature creates a different method with a different bytecode signature which could override implement different method in some superclass, etc.

Depending on use case you can use method overloading or default arguments or - in your case - ignore one parameter during application:

```
class ConcreteFoo extends AbstractFoo {
  override def func: (A, B) => Unit = (_, b) => Bar2.func(b)
}
```